# Meaning of menghe

Tags: meaning

Can anyone provide some possible meanings of "menghe" to Chinese speakers?  I am intentionally not providing the context as I think there may be more than one possible answer and I don't want to lead anyone towards a particular answer.  Thanks!

Comment: see Wikipedia for 3 蒙河,      
蒙河铁路(是中国云南省红河州的一条铁路), 锰合金  měnghéjīn manganese alloy

Comment: Most probably a name.

Comment: This should be closed. You cannot ask a Chinese two syllable word without tones and context!

Comment: @Ludi He made that on purpose.

Comment: @EnricoBrasil I am aware and find it very rude. Is the helper supposed to propose all combinations of the various surnames Meng with possible given names, as well as sentences containing surnames Meng and He in all kinds of contexts and everything else that may come to mind!?

Comment: @Ludi I wasn't trying to be rude and I'm sorry if it was received that way. I thought this was a place to get help with Chinese. As a Chinese novice, I didn't know that 2 syllables without tones poses a problem. I guess a more helpful response would have been to simply point out the inherent difficulty in the question. I (and other beginners) would have learned something from that without feeling like I'd done something wrong (which I certainly didn't want to do) and it wouldn't have made me hesitant to ask questions here again (for fear my ignorance of Chinese will somehow offend again).

Comment: @Kairei I realise my assessment may have been too harsh as well. Chinese, Japanese and several other languages posess a great number of homophones. In retrospect I realised that, as a speaker of a completely different language, you might not be aware of that. I am sorry. If you provide questions with context (such as longer sentences) there won't be a problem understanding and helping you. I still maintain this is a great place for learners and wish not to be the reason of your departure.

Comment: @Ludi No problem, and thanks for the additional info. I will definitely provide context when I can but in this case, strange as it may seem, I literally just had those 6 letters.

Comment: Btw, I see I got some other downvotes and would just like to point out that I used the "meaning" tag on this question which if you mouse over it actually says "Questions ... with or without a context..."  So, whoever runs this site has explicitly said it is appropriate to ask meaning questions without context. If there was some other reason for the downvotes, I'd appreciate some elaboration on why so I can make sure any future questions are appropriate.

Comment: @Kairei I like that you pay attention to the tags! The idea (as I see it) would have been to provide an identifiable word or phrase. An unidentifiable word without context would be a bit of a stretch ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those that tried to offer helpful information. I found a local Chinese speaker who was willing to help and think I found the answer I was looking for. In addition to being a name, as pointed out by @ElpieKay (thanks!), it can also be 孟河 which seems similar to the answer by @user6065 (looks like one character matches at least). Anyway, apparently it is a small town where a style of traditional Chinese medical treatment originated around 200 BC.

Comment: It is akin to a Chinese speaker asking an English speaker :" What T.F.A.U.T" means, without any background information, this question is meaningless because any number of answers could be given."

Comment: For example: that fat ass on U tube / Time for an universal test / those flying axes are useful toys